# Getting URL of browser-based WPF application

Tags: wpf, xbap

Is there way to get a current browser location URL in WPF browser application XBAP? I mean a location from where the application is loaded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look http://learnwpf.com/Posts/Post.aspx?postId=dec2f67d-b80f-4773-ba02-35506b2250e9